# Formula to return the date only when that date actually occurs

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Is there a formula I can use that will return the date but only when that date actually occurs, and otherwise is blank.

So for example in cell A1 the formula would for today return 15/01/2024, tomorrow cell A2 will return 16/01/2024, but for today cell A2 is blank until tomorrow.

I hope this makes sense.

To take it a step further, is there a way to make it so it only returns the date on a Monday, so once again for today it would return 15/01/2024 in cell A1, but cell A2 will remain blank until 22/01/2024 (next Monday)

I tried using combinations of TODAY and WEEKDAY but can't figure out how to make it do what I want.

Comment: Have you tried combining TODAY and IF?

Comment: Format DAY(NOW()) to give "Monday" then test "Monday" = "Monday"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to combine both conditions with an `IF` and `AND`:

If your dates are for example A1:A10

`=IF(AND(A1 = TODAY(),WEEKDAY(A1,2)=1),A1,"")`

and then pull the formula to the right.

This way you check:

- If the date is today's date `A1 = TODAY()`
- If the date is on a Monday `WEEKDAY(A1,2) =1`
  the `,2` signifies the week starting on the Monday and ending on a Sunday

Answer (score 0):

If you start on Monday, next Monday will be seven days later and so on.
Let's try a formula (in `A4`):

```
=IF(TODAY()=Start_date+Step*(ROW()-ROW(A$4)),TODAY(),"")
```

`Start_date` is a date from which you start counting. If you need Mondays it must be a Monday.
`Step` is the difference between dates you want to show. If you need each day you enter 1 into this cell.
`A$4` in the formula is address of the cell where you start your list.
Format the result as date and copy the formula down as required.
[image: Dates]

Answer (score 0):

For your starting date, use this formula:

```
=IF(TODAY()>=DATEVALUE("8/01/2024"),DATEVALUE("8/01/2024"),"")
```

This simply checks if today is after the date you enter in the formula.

[image]

For the rest of the dates, use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(TODAY()>=A2+7,A2+7,""),"")
```

This checks if today is greater than the previous date plus 7 days. It is wrapped in `IFERROR` to prevent the error of adding 7 to a blank cell. If your first date is a Monday, they will all be Mondays.

[image]